# Gridview execute query with custom button

Tags: sql, button, gridview

I have a Database and GridView in Asp.net Like this
[My Gridview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RbxL9.jpg)
I want to change OnayID value 0 to 1 when i click Onayla Button and i wrote some codes but im giving error i dont know why how can i fix it ? i tried some ways but i failure.

`<asp:TemplateField>
                     <ItemTemplate>
                         <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Onayla" CommandName="OnaylaKomutu" />
                     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>`

CODEBEHIND :

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{


    if (e.CommandName == "OnaylaKomutu")
    {

        string UserID = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[7].Text;       
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ElmaCafeDBConnectionString"].ToString());
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE elmacustomers SET OnayID='1' WHERE UserID = @" + UserID, con);
        con.Close();
    }



}
```

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: My error is run time error : http://i.hizliresim.com/vZdd4v.jpg İ couldnt debug because there wasnt write anything

Comment: Are you on remote server?

Comment: Yes im working on a remote server and editing online with Visual Studio FTP

Comment: Is the problem solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error comes from the following line.

```
string UserID = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[7].Text; 
//GridView1.SelectedRow == null
```

It is not easy to calculate `RowIndex` from `GridViewCommandEventArgs` object. Much better is to add `CommandArgument='<%#Eval("UserID")%>'` to the `<asp:Button ... />`. Then you will have

```
string UserID = e.CommandArgument;
```

When you fix first error you will have another issue

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE elmacustomers SET OnayID='1' WHERE UserID = @" + UserID, con); //in effect "...where UserID = @123"
```

Valid code can look like this.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE elmacustomers SET OnayID='1' WHERE UserID = @UserID", con);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = UserID; 
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); //You forget to execute
```

Comment: I did ur fixes , but im giving now  System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.   at  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

Comment: And ide said to me i must cast e.CommandArgument and ı added this string UserID = (e.CommandArgument).ToString();

Comment: Change to `SqlDbType.Varchar`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are not handling the custom error properly. And there seem to some error in your code(let's see about that error later).  And to make this go away, add the line below under `<system.web>` tag of your `web.config`

```
<customErrors mode="Off" defaultRedirect=""/>
```

OR

```
<customErrors mode="Off"/>
```

**UPDATE**

```
string UserID = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[7].Text;//  This  is wrong in RowCommand Event
```

Instead use thie

```
int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
string UserID = GridView1.Rows[index].Cells[9].Text;
```

And
    Add command argument to `Onayla` Button in  the `TemplateField`.

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Onayla" CommandName="OnaylaKomutu" CommandArgument='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container, "RowIndex")%>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Looks like there are lots of error. Here

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE elmacustomers SET OnayID=1 WHERE UserID = " + UserID, con); //remove @ & single quote(')
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); //forgot to execute the command
```

Comment: Oh thanks a lot for this i did and i give some error instrutions like this : System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
string UserID = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[7].Text;

Comment: Are these `Edit`, `Delete` & `Onayla` button in the same column?

Comment: No , Onayla Button in ItemTemplate

Comment: try changin the index `[7]` here GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[7].Text; to `[9]`. You must start the counting form 0

Comment: I m giving same problem like the another answer :  System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format. at int index = Convert.ToInt16(e.CommandArgument);

Comment: System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.

Comment: did you add the commandArgument as given int the answer otherwise you won't get the `rowIndex`

Comment: yes i changed to    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Onayla" CommandName="OnaylaKomutu" CommandArgument='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container, "rowIndex")%>'/>

Comment: and you reload the GridView. Replace (int) with Convert.ToInt32(). Int16 was for `short`. Sorry

Comment: Okey i did , but now when i pressed button only page refreshing we got rid of errors just :)

Comment: No not fixed now not affected anything only refreshing page when pressed Onayla button

Comment: Let's see if we are getting the correct userid. Put a new `Label` say `Label1` set the userid as it's text. `Label`.Text = UserID after this line `string UserID = GridView1.Rows[index].Cells[9].Text;`

Comment: that means we are not getting the userid.  try changing the index to [8].

Comment: I tried another values nothing changed I think UserID string null ?

Comment: add your entire Gridview in the question

Comment: Sorry ?  what can i do ?

Comment: .asp side gridview : http://www.codesend.com/view/3c5490a71f519c6bb58cfb5f1b8bfab9/

Comment: Structure of Gridview here is totally different from the Image in the question. The actual index is [3]. `string UserID = GridView1.Rows[index].Cells[3].Text;`. Now I believe it will work. Don't chage the GridView. If you want to change it, you need to change the index accordingly

Comment: Noo not working i changed to 3 :( Only refreshing page

Comment: do you get the UserID in the Label? And you won't get the updated data after the click. You have to get the data from database and bind to the gridview again. Also do not forget to check the database to make sure the update is working or not

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for answers . I fixed my question thanks to you. @jonju
Here answer : 
ASP.NET

```
 <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Onayla"  OnClick="OnaylaButton_Click"/>

C#
protected void OnaylaButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

{
        int index = GridView1.SelectedRow.DataItemIndex;
        string UserID = GridView1.Rows[index].Cells[3].Text;
        Label2.Text = UserID;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ElmaCafeDBConnectionString"].ToString());
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE elmacustomers SET OnayID=1 WHERE UserID =' " + UserID + "'", con);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        GridView1.DataBind();

        Label_Uyarı.Visible = false;
    }
```